# npm start errors reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-start

Every time I try to start my react project it gives me these errors

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\Desktop\reactjs-basics-master\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\Desktop\reactjs-basics-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-06T11_19_44_754Z-debug.log

Mohamed Badrawy@Mohamed5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/reactjs-basics-master       
$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\Desktop\reactjs-basics-master\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\Desktop\reactjs-basics-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-06T11_25_12_169Z-debug.log
```

I tried to remove package.json and node modules then install npm again and nothing happend, also tried to delete npm cache and nothing happend

Comment: This error is pretty self explanatory - you're typing `npm start` in a directory where there is no `package.json` file. When you say "start your react project" - what do you mean?

Comment: Add package.json , then npm install then npm start ..

Comment: do `cd my-app`, then `npm start` if you have already created a react project (steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't have the `package.json` file. If you claim you had that file, try removing the file and run `npm init` again on your project directory.

Comment: after I did that the errors reduced but still there are some errors................................................................................ found npm ERR! missing script: start npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-07T06_02_13_936Z-debug.log –

Comment: You're missing the script `start` in your file.

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! notes@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the notes@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-07T11_40_08_104Z-debug.log
....................... now for some reason it's a whole new error

Comment: the problem just needed to install npm then npm start and solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If dont have package.json file in your react project it will throw error like this so you
run below command inside your react project and it will add package.json file

```
npm init
```

You can refer this link for how to add package.json file 
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Comment: after I did that the errors reduced but still there are some errors................................................................................



 found 
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohamed Badrawy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-07T06_02_13_936Z-debug.log

Comment: check you have npm start scripts inside package json?